# Java Stream forEach with BufferedReader execute time

Tags: java, java-stream, java-io

When I'm using `Stream.forEach()` with `sorted()` and without, Its behavior is not the same. I.e. `System.out.println` gets executed in the different order.

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
r.lines().limit(4).forEach(System.out::println);
```

When I'm providing as an input

```
a
b
c
d
```

then I'm getting the following result:

[image]

But, when I'm using the following code:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
r.lines().limit(4).sorted().forEach(System.out::println);
```

The result with the same input would be:

[image]

When I didn't use `sorted()`, the `println` in `forEach`
is being called immediately. But if I use `sorted()`,
`println` is called only when I put all the data.

Why does this happening?

Comment: Because you've asked it to sort four lines?

Comment: `.sorted()` must know *all* data before it can sort them and only after sorting `forEach` can be executed. Since `limit(4)` states that there will be 4 elements it needs to wait for it.

Comment: If I just look at it, that's definitely the right idea. But when I think about detail, I can't  understand why this problem works like this.

Answer (score 3):

`sorted()` is a **stateful operation**, which processes all the elements in the stream in one go, because there's no way to sort the data manipulating with the stream elements one-by-one like *stateless operations* (`filter()`, `map()`, etc.) do.

Sorted allocates a new array in memory, dumps all the stream elements into it and sorts it.

If you remove `limit()` from your code, `forEach()` would never be called because sorted would continue to consume elemens.